# How can I transfer world on Minecraft BE from Windows 10 to Linux?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

From (Windows 10)

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

To (CentOS)

```
/opt/minecraft_be_server/worlds
```

I sent the world data to virtual private server by SFTP.

After that, I restarted the server and connected to the Minecraft server, but the data of the sent world was not read and another new world was created.

I also changed the level-name in the server.properties appropriately and changed the directory permissions to minecraft:minecraft.

How can I transfer the world onto Linux?

Comment: Can you not just zip the world folder and then move the folder to Linux and unzip it in there?

Comment: Is the server a bedrock server or a Java server, can I ask?

Answer (score -1):

First off you need to create a backup. Do that by selecting a world and click "edit" and you should be able to click on "Make Backup"

Once you've created a backup copy of that zip folder and put it to a USB or something.

Then in another computer open up Minecraft at then click on any world and click on "edit" and "open worlds folder" in that folder extract that zip file. Once extract click on it and that file inside is your world. Put that file inside the extracted backup folder back into the worlds folder (it's a folder called saves")

Comment: Incorrect. Your answer is for the Java Edition of Minecraft. This question talks about the Bedrock Edition of Minecraft. Please read the question more carefully.

Answer (score -1):

The world file my be corrupted, or may be in a file format that is for windows-only. I would suggest checking to make sure the world folder has come intact to the server and that the world file is correctly formatted to exFAT or another linux-compatible filesystem.

Comment: There is a Bedrock Edition *server* for Linux, and this is what OP is talking about. There are no BE clients for Linux, but you can connect to the Linux server from any regular BE client.

Comment: huh, the mojang website lists it as ubuntu-only.

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux - and with a bit of work you can get its binaries to run on other Linux distributions; in particular [alien](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alien-pkg-convert) can convert .deb (debian/ubuntu packages) to .rpm (RHEL/CentOS)

Comment: Cool!  I will amend my awnser to only have world-fixing suggestions.